# Setting starting point for Graphics.DrawPath paint method

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm currently using the `GraphicsPath` to add a curve into a `graphic`.

I'm not sure which object and how I should change to make the curve start from a point X, Y of my choice (instead of 0,0).

```
PointF[] p = // xxx the code to populate the array with points
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddCurve(p);

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
{
   using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) 
      g.DrawPath(Pens.White, path);

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Which Object do i set the initial starting point, so that it does not start drawing the line from `0,0` ??

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN GraphicsPath.AddCurve:

*The curve begins at the point in the array specified by the offset parameter and includes the number of points (segments) specified by numberOfSegments.*

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms142523(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms142523%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So if you use the overload without offset, you can asume offset is 0, so it will begin to draw at p[0]

If what you tried to mean is that you want to set a drawing offset (displace the coordinate system 0,0) then you can apply a transform with Graphics.TranslateTransform.

Comment: That's to tell what item in the array to start, right? I'm actually trying to specify WHERE in the image (which is 100px by 100px) to draw the line so ideally I should choose to see the curve start drawing from the middle of the image

Comment: Read again, the curve begins at..., so, if p[0] is {100, 100} you will start drawing at 100,100

Comment: I understand that. My question is different. In my mind, the GraphicsPath draws the curve. Then the g.DrawPath applies that curve into a bitmap. If that's the case, I would like to tell the bitmap to put that curve in the middle of the image as if I were doing centering in HTML.

Comment: The path has exact coordinates, if your path starts at 10,10 when you draw it will be at 10,10...

Comment: I'm ok with that. So my real question is this: "how can I move that path around on a larger image?" ...or do I need to code the difference when  I'm adding the actual points into the array?? I'm somehow assuming the Graphics.DrawPath should be able to tell where to put that path.